# Место причастного оборота

Tags: причастный-оборот, порядок-слов

Здравствуйте. Есть ли разница между предложениями "Я прочитал о событии, случившемся вчера" и "Я прочитал о случившемся вчера событии"? Важно ли, в каком месте предложения стоит причастный оборот?

Comment: Важно для обособления либо необособлении оборота. Смысловой и стилистической разницы нет.

Answer (score 2):

Разница есть, хотя оба варианта грамматически корректны. Первый вариант стилистически нейтрален (все элементы сказанного новы и *одинаково информативны* для собеседника) и *по употреблению* характерен для упоминания о событии, о факте которого собеседник предположительно **не знает** (я прочитал, что произошло некоторое событие - было это вчера); за этим возможно раскрытие содержания прочитанного. Во втором варианте есть некоторый акцент на то, что имется в виду событие, о котором второй собеседник, вероятно, **знает** (что касается известного вам вчерашнего события, я прочёл о нём следующее) причём речь идёт о том, что говорящий из прочитанного узнал либо о факте события (и сообщает, что теперь он тоже о нём знает), либо он хочет сообщить новые подробности, где-то описанные.

Comment: А это, пардон, сами сочинили? Или где-то прочитали?

Answer (score 0):

Я прочитал о событии, случившемся вчера. Или: Я прочитал о случившемся вчера событии.

**Кажется, что это одно и то же**, трудно найти разницу в семантике двух сообщений. Но всё дело в том, что предложения эти **учебного плана, то есть придуманы в качестве примеров.** В реальной разговорной ситуации это могло бы звучат так: Я тут прочитал об интересном  событии, случившемся вчера. Или: Я тут прочитал о случившемся вчера интересном событии.

Ясно, что второй вариант звучит надуманно, но вот почему?  Если определить коротко, то во втором предложении имеются проблемы с **коммуникативностью** речи. Сначала вы должны сообщить собеседнику об интересном событии  (ситуация 1), а потом добавить, что оно случилось вчера (ситуация  2). А вот смесь из двух ситуаций плохо воспринимается на слух.

Всё имеет определенный смысл, поэтому разница между двумя формами (обособленной или необособленной) тоже есть, и дело тут не только в запятых.

**Грамматическая справка** (для чего обособляются члены предложения, материал взят из современной грамматики русского языка)

1) Предложения с обособленными членами являются полиситуативными, то есть в них сообщается о более чем одной ситуации, например: У дома росли березки, чахлые и  низенькие (они были чахлые и низенькие). При обособлении полиситуативность подчеркивается, при этом обособленный член становится еще **одним смысловым центром предложения.** **С точки зрения коммуникативности (целевой направленности речи),** обособленные члены выражают выделенное  сообщение.

2) Обособленные члены синонимичны придаточным предложениям: Стая тяжело поднялась над водой, испугавшись неведомого шума (так как испугалась неведомого шума).

3) **Общей причиной**  обособления второстепенных членов всех видов  является их смысловое и коммуникативное выделение (**что выделить и с какой целью выделить).**

Comment: >> *В реальной разговорной ситуации это могло бы звучат так: Я тут прочитал об интересном событии, случившемся вчера. Или: Я тут прочитал о случившемся вчера интересном событии.

Ясно, что второй вариант звучит надуманно, но вот почему?* Ясно, что ОБА варианта, если уж речь идет о разговорной ситуации, звучат надуманно. В разговорной речи подобного рода обороты, хоть обособленные, хоть необособленные, встречаются очень редко. Кстати, почему вы повели речь о разговорной ситуации? В вопросе об этом ни слова.

Comment: Любое сообщение  в реальной ситуации должно иметь признак коммуникативности, то есть должно быть понятно,  с какой целью и к кому вы обращаетесь. Только с таким речевым материалом можно работать, то есть  серьезно анализировать его грамматику.  Поэтому все примеры желательно брать из  существующих текстов  любого стиля (научного, делового, разговорного), а не придумывать. Я не могу себе представить, что кто-то кому-то дословно говорит: "Я прочитал о событии, случившемся вчера". Такое предложение обязательно надо как-то распространить, чтобы вписать его в реальную жизнь

Comment: Почему обязательно "говорит"? А если пишет? Что, к примеру, в публицистическом тексте такой фразы не может быть? Да навалом. Причем хоть в первом вареанте, хоть во втором.

Comment: Можете говорить, можете писать -  без разницы, в любом случае вы рассчитываете  что-то кому-то и с какой-то целью сказать.  А если вы просто  придумали предложение для примера, оно вполне может оказаться лишенным этой необходимой коммуникативной функции.